# Battlefield 3 all stats lost

Tags: battlefield-3, battlelog

Today I launched Battlelog to set up and play multiplayer, and when going to the load-out screen everything was locked with no progress. When I went back to the main screen, all the stats were reset. Is this permanent or will it come back later?
Note that I'm not premium and thus don't have access to the reset stats feature, so I couldn't have done it on accident that way.

Edit: The activity feed still shows things being unlocked, it's just not in the load out screen anymore

Edit 2: Now it displays the stats intermittently, but in the game it starts over so I'm not really making progress.

Edit 3: this is an old post. there was something temporarily up with their servers but it is not relevant now.

Comment: I would be sending emails to Support too if I were you, this sounds like something that doesn't depend on you, you know, just to be sure. When/if you get an answer, you could post the general solution/explanation here as your own answer (you can) in case others have the same issue in the future.

Comment: today I checked and it says "Game statistics server is down", so I'm guessing something went wrong yesterday. hopefully the info is still intact

Answer (score -1):

I've heard of people who got temporarily banned for using an exploit or bug in the game to their advantage or playing on flag run servers (no killing, just capping flags). The account then got temporarily banned from accessing any multiplayer games and your stats were then reset.

I'm not saying you did it, but that's the only logical explanation I can come up with.

Otherwise contact support and tell them exactly what happened and maybe you'll get your stats back.

Comment: From his edits, it would appear that the game servers were actually down rather than as a result of some type of cheating.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/209674)

Comment: @BanhMiDacBiet The game servers might have been down at times, but it will <b>never</b> influence your stats. I've been playing Battlefield since Battlefield 3's release, so I can assure you that I'm not just making things up. The only way your stats can be reset is either you do it manually, but you have to be premium (this is not the case as he has stated that he does not own a premium account), or when cheating or playing on flag run servers (don't kill anyone, just capture flags).<p> So he either played on a flag run server, or he used a bug in the game to his advantage.

Comment: @Vemonus I feel that I did give a good answer to the question, as I have stated what the cause may be of the problem may be and since there is no solution to the problem other than contacting support, I did not provide any solution, only advice.

Comment: @JacobusMostert "Game statistics server is down" was the error message received during this issue. The stats were also intermittently showing, in line with what happens when servers are not handling load properly. With the information presented, it's safe to say it was due to game server issues and not cheating/exploiting bugs.

Comment: @BanhMiDacBiet It could've been in the beginning because of servers not handling load properly, but after the servers can handle the load again, his stats should've returned. If the poster of the question still has his stats reset after all this time, it wouldn't be because of the servers, it would be because of exploiting/ cheating. If the poster of the original question comes forth and says that his stats are back, then I will take back everything I said, but as of now I still believe cheating or exploiting could've lead to his stats being reset, event though the servers were also overloaded

Comment: @JacobusMostert OP has made an edit saying it was a temporary issue when the servers were down. At the time of his posting there were no answers, which is why this was left unanswered.

Comment: @BanhMiDacBiet Then I take back everything I said and we can can close this question

Answer (score -2):

I think EA may be doing maintenance on the servers, judging by the "Game statistics server is down".

Comment: OP's post was two years ago. It's very unlikely that the stats server has been down the entire time.